# In Firebase's Realtime Database, is the following true about removing all listeners from a 'path'?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database:

```
a: {
  b: 1,
  c: 2
}
```

```js
function add(params) {
  db.ref(`a`).orderByKey().equalTo(`c`).on('child_changed', (e) => {
    console.log("red");
  })
}

function remove(params) {
  db.ref(`a`).off();
}
```

`add` attaches listener & `remove` successfully removes the listener (thereby stopping `add` from logging out `"red"`).

Is it true that to remove all listeners of a 'reference' (e.g. `db.ref('a')`), you don't need to specify the ordering functions (`orderByKey()`) & querying functions (`equalTo`) (as demonstrated in `remove`)?

For instance, I **didn't** have to write something like: `db.ref('a').orderByKey().equalTo('c').off()`

Comment: The question is unclear. [Callbacks are removed by calling the off() method on your Firebase database reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#detach_listeners) Adding or removing a listener is independent of adding or updating data within a node. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that something like `db.ref('a').off();` removes all the possible listeners on `db.ref('a')` no matter the different permutations of ordering functions & querying functions they have i.e. `db.ref('a').orderByKey().equalTo('c').on('child_changed', callback) & `db.ref('a').orderByKey()` will always be removed by `db.ref('a').off()`

Comment: .off removes *all observers of any kind* from THAT NODE only, not any child nodes. From the docs: *Calling off() on a parent listener does not automatically remove listeners registered on its child nodes*

Comment: @Jay I interpret your statement to confirm what I think which is why I gave an example to be sure. I'm interpreting words 'observers', 'node', 'reference' (which is what the docs use) to mean something like `db.ref('a')`.

Comment: I don't know what your `db` represents but yes, that a reference to a child node `a` in Firebase. You should take the time to learn a little about NoSQL databases as it will clarify why they have nodes; parent and child, which are akin to a dictionaries key: Value pairs.